# Ubuntu 12.04 freezes after login with 3 screens not mirrored. ATI Radeon HD 6870

Tags: 12.04, ati, monitor

I have 3 screens that runs on 1 ati radeon hd 6870. I tried to turn of mirror mode but it gave me the following errors:

**The selected configuration for displays could not be applied**
required virtual size does not fit available size: requested=(4800, 900), minimum=(320, 200), maximum=(1600, 1600).

**Failed to apply configuration: %s**
GDBus.Error:org.gtk.GDBus.UnmappedGError.Quark._gnome_2drr_2derror_2dquark.Code3: required virtual size does not fit available size: requested=(4800, 900), minimum=(320, 200), maximum=(1600, 1600)

After that I installed the ati catalyst driver 12.6 and changed it in catalyst. It asks for a reboot to take effect. After the reboot it seems to work for the passwordbox is only on the main screen. But as soon as I entered my password. The main screen goes black and my kb & ms is unresponsive. I can't open a tty or anything. I updated the kernel to 3.4 but then I couldn't install the catalyst driver so I then went to 3.3.6. but it still freezes after the password is entered. I can login through tty.

Here is my xorg.conf file:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "aticonfig Layout"
    Screen      0  "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0" 0 0
EndSection

Section "Module"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
    Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
    Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
    Option      "DPMS" "true"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "0-DFP5"
    Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
    Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
    Option      "DPMS" "true"
    Option      "PreferredMode" "1600x900"
    Option      "TargetRefresh" "60"
    Option      "Position" "1600 0"
    Option      "Rotate" "normal"
    Option      "Disable" "false"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "0-DFP11"
    Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
    Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
    Option      "DPMS" "true"
    Option      "PreferredMode" "1600x900"
    Option      "TargetRefresh" "60"
    Option      "Position" "3200 0"
    Option      "Rotate" "normal"
    Option      "Disable" "false"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "0-DFP10"
    Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
    Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
    Option      "DPMS" "true"
    Option      "PreferredMode" "1600x900"
    Option      "TargetRefresh" "60"
    Option      "Position" "0 0"
    Option      "Rotate" "normal"
    Option      "Disable" "false"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
    Driver      "fglrx"
    Option      "Monitor-DFP5" "0-DFP5"
    Option      "Monitor-DFP11" "0-DFP11"
    Option      "Monitor-DFP10" "0-DFP10"
    BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0"
    Device     "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
    DefaultDepth     24
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Virtual   4800 1600
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Please help. 3 mirrored displays aren't useful.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to setup the 3 monitors. I reinstalled ubuntu and used it's default open source drivers and created the /etc/X11/xorg.conf file

```
sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

and added the following:

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier      "Configured Video Device"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
        Identifier      "Configured Monitor"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier      "Default Screen"
        Monitor         "Configured Monitor"
        Device          "Configured Video Device"
        SubSection "Display"
                Viewport   0 0
                Virtual   4800 900
                Depth     24
        EndSubSection
EndSection
```

the virtual 4800 900 must be the total of your screens resolution eg. (1600 * 3 = 4800)

Then I went to display... and turned of the mirrored display option.
Just don't rearange the screens. That makes it crash as soon as you apply it.

Another thing I noticed is after I applied the updates the 2nd screen had strange shadows and windows would leave ghosts. The 3rd screen would flicker every now and then.

To fix that go to display and turn the mirror mode on and off again.

*EDIT

I found a way that works better. Install the 3.5 kernel and xorg-edgers

http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/xorg-edgers

http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/xorg-edgers/precise/main/base/xserver-xorg-video-ati